# Crossbow expert + hand crossbow + buckler

Tags: dnd-5e, feats

Like the title says can you use a hand crossbow with a buckler on the other arm and still fire twice with crossbow expert? Crossbow expert allows you to ignore the loading quality.

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Sorry for the double post.  I’m not familiar with the mechanics of this site.  Could you please add link to the previously answered question.   Thanks

Comment: The link should be in the post notice at the top of your question, but also [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65363/52137).